# Integrating the product $x|x|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate the product $x|x|$ with respect to $x$. That is, compute $\int x|x| dx$. I want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

So, $|x| = -x$ when $x < 0$ and $|x| = x$ when $x > 0$ and vanishes for $x = 0$. That means I should write $\int_{-\infty}^{0}-x\cdot x dx + \int_0^{\infty} x\cdot x dx = -\frac{x^3}{3} \mid_{-\infty}^{0} + \frac{x^3}{3}\mid_{0}^{\infty}$ but this isn't really making sense as the left term is zero and the right term goes to $\infty$.

Comment: What is it now? Indefinite or definite integral?

Comment: Indefinite. But actually I thought I had to introduce the bounds to split the integrand into positive and negative parts. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I:=\int x\lvert x\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x=\int x^2 \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$u=\lvert x\rvert,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{x}\,\mathrm{d}u$
$$I=\int u^2 \,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{u^3}{3}+C=\frac{\lvert x\rvert x^2}{3}+C$$

Comment: Wait, how can this substitution work? $du = 2xdx$, but there is still a $\frac{1}{|x|}$ term to deal with.

Comment: I meant to write $u=\lvert x\rvert$. The calculation is still right.

Comment: Ah, I see the edit now. Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) allows us to write any real number $x$ as

$$|x| = \mathrm{sgn}(x)x.$$
We may then integrate by parts to obtain

$$\int x|x|~dx=\int \mathrm{sgn}(x)x^2~dx=|x|x^2-\int 2x|x| ~dx,$$

where $\frac{d}{dx} |x|=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ on non-zero sets. This yields

$$\int x|x| ~dx = \frac{|x|x^2}{3}+C~.$$